# Adding high amount of yeast to sugar wash

Tags: yeast, sugar

Given that I would not care for good flavor.  Would adding 1 lb of hydrated bakers yeast to of a 5 gallon of sugar wash with 17 lbs of sugar make the fermentation process any faster?  How much time would the process take in right temperature?  Both sugar and yeast used are dirt cheap where I am.  I'm going to distill the wash then flavor with strong whiesky essence afterwards so I don't care too much about the flavour of the wash.

Cheers, 
S

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** 
Adding more cell count to the wash will reduce fermentation time.

Its possible to skip growth phase lag with a full pitch of yeast.

Answer (score 0):

If you google some liquor recipes like for rum people often make 'yeast bombs' to make their sugar wash ferment really quickly. Ive read recipes where people had 50L of wash made in about 2 days by adding a cup of bakers yeast. Obviously youll want to scale down for 5 gallons ( around 22 litres? ) but basically the more you add the faster it'll ferment.

For example: http://homedistiller.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5994

Answer (score 0):

17 lbs (nearly 8Kg) of sugar in 5 gallons (24L) of water will be near the top end of what most yeasts can handle. And many "bakers yeasts" are not really a high attenuation and high alcohol strain. It may be that the planned fermentation will stick or even never start when such a high sugar concentration and "bakers yeast".

It may be a better strategy to use an high alcohol yeast (eg Champagne or even a "Turbo yeast") and/or make a number of additions of sugar as the fermentation progresses. At the proposed strength it may well be better to use dextrose/glucose (brewing sugar) rather than sucrose (table sugar).